# How to get the current selected value on select dropdown? And how to pass it on a php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How do I get the current selected value on my dropdown? And pass it on my php variable?

```
<select name="f_country_id">
<option value="0">-Select country-</option>
<option value="1">Brazil</option>
<option value="2">Canada</option>
<option value="3" selected>Denmark</option>
<option value="4">Philippines</option>
<option value="5">USA</option>
</select>
```

Then  **onChange**  i need also to get the new value selected. And output it on a page inside a php variable.

Do I need to reload the page and use the `GET["f_country_id"]` as url variable to achieve it. Because I'll be using the id value for my search.

Please help and advise.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried yet ?

Comment: I suggest query params to manipulate current page's data , use GET params

Comment: `$("[name="f_country_id"] option:selected").val()` use ajax or form submit to pass value to php

Comment: _"output it on a page inside a php variable"_ On what page? Where? New window? Replace this page? Iframe? Frames? Please clarify your question and what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Im just using one page for my search page. I just need to get the current selected value and pass it to a php variable so i can use it on a query.

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
  function getID(sel)
  {
   alert(sel.value);
   <?php $selVal = sel.value; ?>
  }
 </script>

<?php 
 echo $selVal;
?>



<select name="f_country_id" onchange="getID(this);" >
<option value="0">-Select country-</option>
<option value="1">Brazil</option>
<option value="2">Canada</option>
<option value="3" selected>Denmark</option>
<option value="4">Philippines</option>
<option value="5">USA</option>
</select>

Dont know how to pass the JS var into PHP var